Transaction isolation level for financial transactions
Let's assume we have an application that must transfer funds from account A to account B.
Let's assume that database is MySQL (though I'd appreciant an answer for Postgres too).
Account A balance: 20
Account B balance: 0

Transaction 1 (TX1): transfer 10 from A to B
Transaction 2 (TX2): transfer 15 from A to B

TX1 and TX2 happen simultaneously.
Now, this is program logic steps:

Read FROM balance
Validate it's more than transfer amount
Save updates. For example in transaction 1 updates are:

    update BALANCES set balance = balance - 10 where id = A
    update BALANCES set balance = balance + 10 where id = B

Questions:
1. What transaction isolation level should I use for this transaction?
2. Is transaction isolation level enough or I must explicitly use pessimistic locking?
Let me elaborate. Taking for example SERIALIZABLE level in MySQL, when you read a record within a transaction, record gets locked with shared lock.
A shared lock does not prevent other transactions from placing a shared lock and reading the data.
Effectively, both transactions get a shared lock on A and B, then TX1 tries to make an update and receive an exclusive lock. It can't do it as TX2 already holds a shared lock.
So we get a deadlock: one of the transactions will get rolled back, and we will have to hang for a while (default is 30 or more seconds).
From where I see, a money transfer like this is not implementable with SERIALIZABLE isolation alone. Instead, it looks like we can go with READ_COMMITTED but explicitly request an exclusive lock right at the moment of data reading: "select * from BALANCES where id = A FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;". Hence, no other transaction can obtain shared locks on records hence preventing a deadlock.
Please help me understand this.

There is a whole chapter about this subject: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html

Your conclusion is correct, you need to explicitly take a lock to prevent problems. In other words, pessimistic locking.
The statement you show with FOR UPDATE actually acquires an exclusive lock, not a shared lock. MySQL syntax uses FOR SHARE to acquire a shared lock (this used to be known as LOCK IN SHARE MODE in MySQL 5.x).
In fact, you should also lock the destination row for B at the same time, to prevent deadlocks in case a transaction is transferring money from B to A concurrently.
Locking is more important for this task than choosing between transaction isolation levels. This is why there's no clear answer when you ask "which transaction isolation level should I use?"

Thank you! I updated the typo about shared lock.

Given your answer, it's not quite clear for me a good use case for SERIALIZABLE isolation level. It's not enough for a mere standard operation. What is this good for then?

SERIALIZABLE as implemented in MySQL causes non-locking reads to become locking reads, acquiring shared locks. So you can read a row and block any updates to that row until you finish your transaction. This avoids phantom updates — i.e. you read a row and use its values in your client application, but unknown to you, someone else has updated the row immediately after you read it.

@BillKarwin correct me if I am wrong, SERIALIZABLE prevents phantom updates, and REPEATABLE READ prevents phantom reads?

@potatoxchip Yes, correct.
